# In jQuery UI: How to use separate html files as content of tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

When I use jQuery UI tabs to create tabbed pages, I have to put contents under all tabs in the same html file, and this causes the file to grow to a huge size.  Is there a way to expose a different html file under each tab without the use of ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put this in each one of the tabs.

```
<!--#include virtual="path to file/include-file.html" -->
```

Comment: Please note, that you can't use this method unles you're leveraging templates, `<script type="x-jquery-tmpl"><!--#include virtual="path/to/my/file.html" --> </script>`

Comment: Don't you need to be running on a server with SSI support to test that? OP might get confused trying it on `file://` protocol

Comment: I didn't know about x-jquery-tmpl, but right now when I tried to learn about it, I saw a message that jQuery team will not support it anymore http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/.  Just wanted to make sure that this is the technology that you proposing, or is that something else?